# Clean way of returning middle index of matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Want a clean way to find the index of the middle of a matrix and if there is no 'middle', then the index of the maximal element surrounding. Note matrices are not always square.

> Ex 1. Input: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`

(1,2)
   (3,4)

So this would return (1,1), because the maximal element surrounding the 'middle' is 4.

> Ex 2. Input: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

(1,2,3)
   (4,5,6)
   (7,8,9)

And this would return (1,1) because that's the index of the middle of the matrix.

Would appreciate a clean way to return said index!

Comment: Define "clean."

Comment: Not a hundred lines of code would be a starter.

Comment: Are these matrices always square?

Comment: No, they're not.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Getting the index of the "middle" should be quite easy.

Comment: I have a solution which essentially just finds the 'middle' or possible middles, then looks for the max if appropriate / returns but I was interested in a more Pythonic way if there is one.

Comment: That's how I'd approach it, but I also haven't closed in Python in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In straight Python:

```
def mid(n): return {(n-1)//2,n//2}
max(((i,j) for i in mid(len(a)) for j in mid(len(a[0]))),
    key=lambda ij: a[ij[0]][ij[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your matrix be a NumPy array.

```
import mumpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
c = np.random.random_integers(100, size=8).reshape(2, -1)
#array([[41, 61, 47, 51],
#       [40, 81, 23, 66]])
```

Check the dimensions, extract the "center", find the maximal value and its coordinates, adjust them:

```
def find_center(a):
    x = (a.shape[0] // 2 if a.shape[0] % 2 else a.shape[0] // 2 - 1, 
         a.shape[0] // 2 + 1)
    y = (a.shape[1] // 2 if a.shape[1] % 2 else a.shape[1] // 2 - 1, 
         a.shape[1] // 2 + 1)
    center = a[x[0]:x[1], y[0]:y[1]]
    argmax = np.unravel_index(center.argmax(), center.shape)
    return argmax[0] + x[0], argmax[1] + y[0] # Adjust
```

Testing:

```
find_center(a)
#(1, 1)
find_center(b)
#(1, 1)
find_center(c)
#(1, 1) - 81!
```